# Entity Framework 6 Generic Repository with AutoMapper slow performance when running find method on remote database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, automapper, predicate

I'm using Entity Framework 6 with Generic Repository, AutoMapper and UnitOfWork. When I use a remote database (VPN connection) it seems that the find method is executing very very slow.

Generic Repository Interface:

```
public interface IRepository<T, T1>
        where T : class, IEntity
        where T1 : class, IEntity
    {
          ....
        List<T1> Find(Expression<Func<T1, bool>> predicate);

    }
}
```

Generic Repository Find method implementation I've tried two options and it seems that the second one is taking less time but is not sufficient (~ 7 min and the first option ~ 10 min)

```
public List<T1> Find(Expression<Func<T1, bool>> predicate)
{
    var listT1 = AutoMapperConfiguration.GetMapperConfiguration().Map<List<T1>>(_dbContext.Set<T>().Where(q => !q.IsDeleted));
    var result = listT1.Where(predicate.Compile()).ToList();

    return result;
}


public List<T1> Find(Expression<Func<T1, bool>> predicate)
{
    var query = _dbContext.Set<T>().Where(q => !q.IsDeleted);   
    return AutoMapperConfiguration.GetMapperConfiguration().Map<List<T1>>(query).AsQueryable().Where(predicate).ToList();
}
```

In Controller I use it like this

```
public PrjUser_ViewModel GetUserByName(string name)
{
    using (var unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkFactory.Create())
    {
        return unitOfWork.PrjUsers.Find(user => user.Name.ToUpper() == name.ToUpper()).FirstOrDefault();

    }

}
```

and in the uow implementation:

```
public IRepository<PrjUser, PrjUser_ViewModel> PrjUsers
{
    get
    {
        var _prjusers = new Repository<PrjUser, PrjUser_ViewModel>(_databaseContext);
        _prjusers.ResetIndexes();
        return _prjusers;
    }
}
```

What can I do to improve the find method execution?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html

Comment: Both versions of your code are basically downloading the entire list of users from the database and filtering in memory, that's why they're slow. In your first version, move the predicate into the query, for example: `_dbContext.Set<T>().Where(q => !q.IsDeleted).Where(predicate)`

Comment: A DbContext is already a multi-entity Unit of Work. A DbSet is already a single-entity Repository. The "generic repository" is an *anti*pattern in this case, making it a lot harder to write and maintain correct code, never mind fast code. For example `SaveChanges` persists *all* changes in a single transaction. That's good. If you have an `Insert` method that calls` SaveChanges` it will also persist any Update or Delete changes. That's not a bug in EF or a design error. It's a problem of the "generic" repository

Comment: I cannot add the predicate into the query like var listT1 = AutoMapperConfiguration.GetMapperConfiguration().Map<List<T1>>(_dbContext.Set<T>().Where(q => !q.IsDeleted).Where(predicate)); because the predicate is of type Expression<Func<T1, bool>> predicate  and is expecting Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate

Answer (score 0):

Both versions of your code are basically downloading the *entire* list of users from the database and filtering in memory, that's why they're slow.

In your first version, move the predicate into the query, for example:

```
public List<T1> Find(Expression<Func<T1, bool>> predicate)
{
    // Note this is still an IQueryable<T> so nothing is executed against the database yet
    var query = _dbContext.Set<T>()
        .Where(q => !q.IsDeleted)
        .Where(predicate);

    return AutoMapperConfiguration.GetMapperConfiguration()
        .Map<List<T1>>(query);
}
```

Comment: It seems like I cannot add the predicate into  var query = _dbContext.Set<T>().Where(q => !q.IsDeleted).Where(predicate); Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<T1, bool>>' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<T, int, bool>>'

Comment: Oh, I see the problem now, you need to map your incoming T1 into T, otherwise you're going to have to query everything in memory.

Comment: Yes and I really don't know how to achive this.